# Dropzone filtering files

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have been trying almost for a week to make this to work i have been trying to filer some files with the  `accept:`  option in dropzone i wanted to allow up to 2 files with type  `'image/png' and 'image/jpeg'`  and when i get to have 2 of those types in dropzone alert user that she or he reach the max and at the same time allowing user to upload songs.

The code works somewhat but if i add to files with audio mime-type then after adding a images it displays the warning for the images but in reality that limit hasn't been reached yet.

```
accept: function(file, done){

  // Variables
  var _this = this.getAcceptedFiles(),
      ext = file.name.split('.')
      jpeg = 'image/jpeg',
      png = 'image/png';


  console.log(this.getAcceptedFiles())
  console.log('added')


  // Adding extension to screen for user to see
  $(file.previewElement.childNodes[1]).children().text(ext[ext.length - 1])

  // function in charge of showing and hiding the info box
  // and in charge of displying scrollbar
  box_show();

  // check if file already exist in list
  if (check_the_same(_this, file)){

    done('File ' + file.name + ' already in exist.');

  }else{

    // if file is a image check if we have more than two in list
    if (file.type == jpeg || png){
      if (more_than_2(_this, file)){

        done('Remember just up to 2 images.');
      }else{

        done();
      }

    }else{
      done()
    }
  }
}
```

**function checking for repeating file** :

```
function check_the_same(_this, file){

  // loop to check if file already exists in added file list
  for(var i = 0; _this.length > i; i++ ){

    // if file name is in already created list show alert    
    console.log($('div#list-container #h').children().length)
    if (file.name == _this[i].name){

      return true
    }

  }

}
```

**function that checks how many images** :

```
function more_than_2(_this, file){

  var num_check = 0;

  for (var i = 0; _this.length > i; i++){
  console.log(_this);

    if (file.type == 'image/jpeg' || 'image/png'){
      console.log(file.type == 'image/jpeg');

      num_check += 1;

      if (num_check >= 2){
        console.log('true')

        return true
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you always doing

```
file.type == 'image/jpeg' || 'image/png'
```

within your loop so if you have 2 files or more in total and you are trying to upload an image, it will fail.

Correct should be :

```
_this[i].type == 'image/jpeg' || 'image/png'
```